# how to implement an efficient to_ascii function in Elixir/ Erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir, ascii

How would you implement an efficient `to_ascii` function in Elixir (or Erlang)?

Scanning each character of a string and calling `String.printable?` seems like a ***very*** bad option

```
  def to_ascii(s) do
    case String.printable?(s) do
      true -> s
      false -> _to_ascii(String.codepoints(s), "")
    end
  end

  defp _to_ascii([], acc), do: acc
  defp _to_ascii([c | rest], acc) when ?c in 32..127, do: _to_ascii(rest, acc <> c)
  defp _to_ascii([_ | rest], acc), do: _to_ascii(rest, acc)
```

Example:

```
s_in = <<"hello", 150, " ", 180, "world", 160>>
s_out = "hello world" # valid ascii only i.e 32 .. 127
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension [with `:into` keyword argument](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#the-into-option):

```rb
s = "hello привет ¡hola!"
for <<c <- s>>, c in 32..127, into: "", do: <<c>>
#⇒ "hello  hola!"

s = <<"hello", 150, "world", 160>>
for <<c <- s>>, c in 32..127, into: "", do: <<c>>
#⇒ "helloworld"
```

Comment: It’s apparently not me; blame José :)

Answer (score 5):

In Erlang

```
1> Bin = <<"hello привет ¡hola!"/utf8>>.
<<104,101,108,108,111,32,208,191,209,128,208,184,208,178,
  208,181,209,130,32,194,161,104,111,108,97,33>>
2> << <<C>> || <<C>> <= Bin, C >= 32, C =< 127 >>. 
<<"hello  hola!">>
3> [ C || <<C>> <= Bin, C >= 32, C =< 127 ].      
"hello  hola!"
```